# Where do I live? (figuring out latitude/longitude from legal documents)

Tags: latitude-longitude, calculate-values, legal-description

I recently bought the [SparkFun RTK Express](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/18442) which looks like a pretty cool little gizmo. I've got some applications for it up in the mountains, but first I want to try it out down here in the suburbs.

I'd like to figure out the lat/lon of the corners of my lot, based on the legal description, and then see if the RTK gives the same answer (within its stated accuracy, of course).  I've got a plat map for the subdivision, but it seems to mostly contain the directions & lengths of lot lines, but not their locations.

How can I figure out the lat/lon of the corners of my lot?

[image: Plat Map of my entire subdivision]

[image: Closeup]

Comment: Can the folks who are downvoting, give some kind of hint what has displeased them?

Comment: You dont say what you have tried, or if you tried anything what is the problem?

Comment: Do you know how to read coordinates off that map? There's lots of things on it that seem to be degrees, minutes and seconds but none of them seem to relate to points or have both a lat and a long. Have you looked at ways to georeference the map, for example using the georeferencer in QGIS? Do you have much GIS experience?

Comment: This isn't a GIS Question -- it's more like a Geography trivia problem, one which isn't well researched, and doesn't have general applicability. The reason we take time to write answers is so that others can apply the Answer to their problem. If you describe a task without any attempt to solve it, you don't yet have a problem.

Comment: I did say what I have tried - I tried contacting the county and getting a copy of the subdivision plat map.  And I did say what the problem is - the plat map contained a lot of "degrees, minutes and seconds but none of them seem to relate to points or have both a lat and a long" (what SpacedMan said).

Comment: No, I have very little GIS experience.  That's why I'm asking for help on StackExchange!  I don't know anything about georeferencers or QGIS.

Comment: Yes, it has general applicability.  I can't be the only person on the planet who wants to know what lat/lon of the corners of their suburban lot.  I did attempt to solve it - I got the plat map, and then (because of my inexperience) I didn't know where to go next.

Answer (score 1):

I got the answer on a [similar question I posted](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/433713/how-do-i-translate-legalese-into-latitude-longitude/433744#433744).

Boulder County has all their [GIS data nicely available online](https://opendata-bouldercounty.hub.arcgis.com/datasets/bouldercounty::parcels/explore?location=40.087819%2C-105.373100%2C11.53), I was able to zoom in on my property, determine its parcel number, filter on that, and then download a GeoJSON file that contains the lat/lon corners.  The plat map is apparently the old-fashioned way to get this information.