# How do I translate legalese into latitude/longitude?

Tags: gps, latitude-longitude, legal-description

I bought some land in the mountains recently, and its location is described like so:

> THAT PORTION OF THE SOUTHWEST 1/4 OF SECTION 25, TOWNSHIP 3 NORTH, RANGE 73 WEST OF THE 6TH P.M., DESCRIBED AS FOLLOWS:

> BEGINNING AT A POINT ON THE SOUTH LINE OF SAID SECTION 25 FROM WHICH POINT THE SOUTHWEST CORNER OF SAID SECTION 25 BEARS WEST, 590.00 FEET, SAID POINT ALSO BEING THE SOUTHEAST CORNER OF THAT TRACT OF LAND CONVEYED TO FANNIE MAE WOMACK BY RICHARD J. ILSE IN DEED RECORDED APRIL 17, 1947 IN BOOK 797 AT PAGE 586; THENCE NORTH, 953.60 FEET; THENCE EAST 675.00 FEET; THENCE NORTH 460.00 FEET; THENCE NORTH 86°13' EAST, 69.00 FEET TO THE WEST LINE OF THAT TRACT OF LAND CONVEYED TO HUGH F. ATKINSON AND MILLICENT ATKINSON BY RICHARD J. ILSE IN DEED RECORDED AUGUST 20, 1948 IN BOOK 830 AT PAGE 594; THENCE SOUTH 1,395.00 FEET TO A POINT ON THE SOUTH LINE OF SAID SECTION 25, A DISTANCE OF 1,469.00 FEET WEST OF THE SOUTH 1/4 CORNER OF SAID SECTION; THENCE WEST, 744.00 FEET TO THE POINT OF BEGINNING, COUNTY OF BOULDER, STATE OF COLORADO.

I'd like to translate that into latitude/longitude so I can take my spiffy new [SparkFun RTK Express](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/18442) up there and see if I can locate those points (within the accuracy of the device, of course - it claims 300 mm).

According to [Earth Point](https://www.earthpoint.us/TownshipsSearchByDescription.aspx), that section has these coordinates:

[image]

And if I type those points into Google Earth, what I get looks like this:

[image: Google Earth]

So assuming that's correct, and I get up there before plate tectonics moves things too far, then can I just calculate the "southwest 1/4" as (lat1+lat2)/2, (lon1+lon2)/2, or do I need to worry about the curvature of the Earth at this small scale?

And then can I just do trigonometry from there, or again do I need to worry about the curvature of the Earth?

It already seems problematic, as the first direction in the legal description says "BEARS WEST" but the bottom line of the section doesn't seem to go due west, should I instead follow the south edge of the section for 590 feet?

### EDIT 1

Dear lord, they make this hard to read.  So when it says

> BEGINNING AT A POINT ON THE SOUTH LINE OF SAID SECTION 25 FROM WHICH POINT THE SOUTHWEST CORNER OF SAID SECTION 25 BEARS WEST, 590.00 FEET, SAID POINT ALSO BEING THE SOUTHEAST CORNER OF THAT TRACT OF LAND CONVEYED TO FANNIE MAE WOMACK BY RICHARD J. ILSE IN DEED RECORDED APRIL 17, 1947 IN BOOK 797 AT PAGE 586

I think they are saying that the first point is the point such that if you go 590 feet "west" (along the south line of the section), you end up at the southwest corner of the section.  Is that right?

### EDIT 2

The parcel shapefile for Boulder County is awesome!  I was able to download where they think the corners of my land are:

```
{
"type": "FeatureCollection",
"name": "Parcels",
"crs": { "type": "name", "properties": { "name": "urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC:1.3:CRS84" } },
"features": [{
   "type": "Feature", "id": 230612290,
   "properties": {
      "OBJECTID": 230612290, "PARCEL_NO": "119725000022",
      "PARCEL_NUM": null, "SHAPEarea": 720163.68297235505,
      "SHAPElen": 4275.5048515807075 },
   "geometry": { "type": "Polygon",
      "coordinates": [ [
         [ -105.518917581208441, 40.192320855458142 ],
         [ -105.518919207102101, 40.191063537462746 ],
         [ -105.521289265701043, 40.191098375370252 ],
         [ -105.521281606881303, 40.190518763875467 ],
         [ -105.521299408163387, 40.188486577020143 ],
         [ -105.518722869580088, 40.188440838834488 ],
         [ -105.518670398553013, 40.191735163288229 ],
         [ -105.518675812144394, 40.192328125363801 ], 
         [ -105.518917581208441, 40.192320855458142 ]
   ] ] } } ] }
```

But here's the strange thing.  According to Boulder County, here's what my land looks like:

[image: Boulder County - land shape]

and that's correct.

If I take the 9 points from the Boulder County JSON file and create points in Google earth, it looks like this:

[image: Google Earth - land shape]

Which confused me at first, but now I understand.  They include all "points of interest" which includes places where two neighboring lots abut.  It appears my neighbor has built his fence a little bit on my land!

Comment: Wow. Maybe you could try asking at https://english.stackexchange.com ?

Comment: Yes, a survey always starts with a POB, a point of beginning, which is usually a locatable monument like a brass cap. But you need a software that works back-n-forth between feet units and degree units. What software are you using?

Comment: You can download the parcel shapefile for the whole of Boulder County here: https://opendata-bouldercounty.hub.arcgis.com/datasets/bouldercounty::parcels/explore?location=40.088014%2C-105.373100%2C11.53

Comment: @Pointdump The parcel shapefile from Boulder County is great!  I've created EDIT 2 talking about my experiences there.  Any idea why those two points would be so wrong?

Comment: Never mind!  I think I figured it out

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Agreed, kinda tough to read. I grabbed the parcel shapefile for Boulder County and went from there using Civil 3D AutoCAD. So best I can figure, your property corners are:

40.18848658,-105.52129941

40.19109838,-105.52128927

40.19106354,-105.51891921

40.19232086,-105.51891758

40.19232813,-105.51867581

40.18844084,-105.51872287
[image]

You can also do a Property Search with your Parcel Number and get more here:
https://maps.boco.solutions/propertysearch/

[image]